# Apply each value of an array to one element until the end of the array is reached?

Tags: javascript

I need to dynamically add values from an array to a custom data attribute in some html elements. For example, let's say I have 12 ".point" elements, I need to apply one of the months, in order, to each of those elements. I have tried a few ways, but I don't think my logic is correct here. I have included my latest attempt below, this only results in "Dec" being applied to the twelve ".point" elements.

JS/jQuery

```
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
var monthsLength = months.length;
for (var i = 0; i < monthsLength; i++) {
    $('.point').attr('data-date', months[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery objects are array-like, so you can grab the matching `.point` elements with a single `$(".point")` call, then index into it; when you index into a jQuery object, you get the raw entry (usually a DOM element) at that index. Here's an ES5-level version:

```
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
var monthsLength = months.length;
var points = $('.point');
for (var i = 0; i < monthsLength; i++) {
    var point = points[i];
    if (!point) {
        break; // Ran out of elements
    }
    point.setAttribute("data-date", months[i]);
}
```

Alternatively, we can drive this via `$(".point").attr`, which has the option of calling a callback:

```
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
$(".point").attr("data-date", function(i) {
    var month = months[i];
    return month;
});
```

Note that the function gets the index of the element passed to it as its first argument.

We don't need to check whether `months[i]` returned a string because if we go beyond the end of the array, `month` will be `undefined`, and the `attr` function doesn't change an element's attribute value if the function returns `undefined`.

Comment: This works great! Thank you for your response. What if I want to do it multiple times with multiple sets of 12 ".points"?

Comment: How it should behave for multiple sets? What if some set has more or less then 12 elements?

Comment: @grahamfk45c - It depends on what you mean by multiple sets of 12 ".points", but that might involve nested loops.

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski - The question didn't say anything about multiple sets (just the comment above). If *the* set has fewer or more than 12 items, it's fine. Fewer just means not all months are used; more means `i` goes past the end of the `months` array and the note in the answer applies (basically, the ones at indexes 12 onward won't have any change to their attribute).

Answer (score 0):

in your current code, you always select all 12 points in each loop. try using [eq selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) when selecting each point in the loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < monthsLength; i++) {
  $('.point').eq(i).attr('data-date', months[i]);
}
```